# TinyMCE method remove does not work in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, tinymce

I´ve worked on the text editor and there are one plugin that was created to putting header and footer (basically a row of table) in the editor and one of the business rules is don´t to permit move the header or footer (My version is 3.3.8 but I tested in the last 3.4.6).

I created a method in the basic_config.js, basically inside of the method "ed.onChange.add(function(ed, l)" to readjust the position of header or footer when the user try to move the table to another place,  like this:

```
               //find out the div of the header
                var elm = tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.get("testeHeader");

               //case the elm move of position...
               if(elm != null) {
                    var txt = tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.getOuterHTML(elm);
                    //method remove does not work in Internet Explorer
                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.remove("testeHeader");
                    //relocates the header to the top
                    $('#editor1_ifr').contents().find('body').prepend(txt);
                }
```

In the Firefox it works but in the Internet Explorer de method remove fail, nothing happers.

There any response for this cause?

There are some form to block the mouse selection of the header or footer of table?

Thank a bunch for all that get help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody().removeChild(elm);
```

instead of

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.remove("testeHeader");
```

Comment: Good tip but in Internet Explorer 8 it doesn´t work too. Just works on Firefox.

Comment: thats pretty wierd, removeChild is one of the basic javascript dom operations. what does $(elm).remove();  do?

Comment: Sorry, but I did some tests and the instructions that you cited and really works on IE8. The problem is "prepend" that IE doesn´t recognize. There are other functions that works on IE to relocate to beginning of page ?